# Flutter on android only uses "release" signingConfig?

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

I'm attempting to use multiple signing configs, one for local development and one for CICD/release. When running flutter run locally (which should use a debug configuration), it still tries to run the release signing, even if I add a --debug flag. Any reason why it wouldn't stick to the debug signingConfig only?

I know it's hitting the release signingConfig since build.gradle throws an error that the file path in `storeFile = file(System.getenv("STORE_FILE"))` is null. If I remove the release signingConfig altogether, it throws an error that the signingConfig for release does not exist

My app/build.gradle is below:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
        def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
   }

   release {
       storeFile = file(System.getenv("STORE_FILE"))
       storePassword System.getenv("STORE_PASSWORD")
       keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
       keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
   }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        println(signingConfigs.debug)
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the keystoreProperties above, out of the android {}
Have you tried using a different keystorePropertiesFile for each config ?